# Spherical circle tangent to spherical line

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

If $u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(0,1,1)$, $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(1,2,1)$, find $r>0$ such that $C(u,r)$ is tangent to $L_v$.

My attempt: I tried to relate $x \cdot u = \cos r$, $x\cdot v = 0$, and $\Vert x \Vert=1$, but, obviously, one more equation is needed, since there are four unknowns here. On the other hand, only $r$ needs to be found, and there are only two vectors $x$ satisfying the needed property. If these vectors $x$ could be found, $r$ could be found as well, but I'm missing something as I don't see how to find these vectors $x$. Some hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you see that there are more than one line? The solution is a cone where v is the vertex.

Comment: I don't see how it is a cone with vertex $v$...

Comment: What is $L_v$? There are infinite lines passing through $v$.

Comment: All the lines that are pass through v create a cone...

Comment: @Aretino, $L_v$ is a spherical line, $L_v = P \cap S^2$, where $S^2$ is a unit sphere, and $P$ is the plane whose normal is $v$.